# How do I use a variable to find the position of an element in a list in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to use **name** as a variable to capture input from the user, but `**actual name of list**.index[]` doesn't seem to work if I were to put a variable into its brackets.

Name of list: nameList

Name of variable: name

```
nameList = ['Tom', 'Joe', 'Mary', 'John', 'Bob', 'Jane']
name = input('Enter name to search :')
nameList.index[]
print('Name', name, 'is found in position', nameList[name], 'in the name list.')
```

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: @schwobaseggl - `list` doesn't have a `find` method.

Comment: `nameList.index(name)`.

Comment: My apologises, I meant nameList.index().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments pretty much answer the question. To be more elaborate, this is how you do it:

```
nameList = ['Tom', 'Joe', 'Mary', 'John', 'Bob', 'Jane']
name = input('Enter name to search :')
print('Name', name, 'is found in position', nameList.index(name), 'in the name list.')
```

However, note that this will throw an error if the name is not present in the list. To avoid that, you should check if the name is present in the list.

```
nameList = ['Tom', 'Joe', 'Mary', 'John', 'Bob', 'Jane']
name = input('Enter name to search :')
if name in nameList:
    print('Name', name, 'is found in position', nameList.index(name), 'in the name list.')
else:
    print ("Name not present in nameList.")
```

Comment: Very interesting. I had always assumed that 'if' only worked with '!=', '=', '>=', '<=', etc.
I also love how you integrated nameList.index(name).

Comment: Good to know! Please upvote and accept the answer if it works for you!

Comment: I will once I get enough reputation. Sorry for the late reply and thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following task as this method.

```
nameList = ['Tom', 'Joe', 'Mary', 'John', 'Bob', 'Jane']
name = input('Enter name to search :')
req_index =0
for item in nameList:
  if(item==name):
    break
  req_index=req_index+1

print('Name', name, 'is found in position', req_index, 'in the name list.')
```

Comment: It seems a little bit too complex, but I suppose I could give it a try.

Comment: Actually it's not that complicated. Just understand that the for loop is itearting over every element in the namelist. item represent the current element in namelist. Your input (name) is compared with item on every iteration. If we find that input is equal to a element in namelist we break the loop. Req index is just used to store the index of current element being inspected.